# Angular 9 Plotly bar chart defaulting to line chart after prod build

Tags: angular, plotly.js

I'm having trouble figuring out why my Plotly bar chart is defaulting to a line chart in an Angular 9 app after the production build. It renders perfectly as a bar chart when running the dev server but renders as a line chart on a prod build. There are no errors or any other problems in production. It's as if the `type: 'bar'` from the data object is getting dropped somehow. I can't find any information on other people having the same issue.

Comment: can you create  demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it works when I recreate a similar example in stackblitz. The only time the bar chart fails to render is after the angular code is compiled.

Comment: give us the demo url to tested and I will try to compile it 

Comment: Thanks so much for offering to help. I was able to get the bar chart to render by removing all the ```buildOptimizer``` and ```aot``` flags. It also worked properly when I imported the ```PlotlyCDNModule```.